# Matlab plotyy and semilogx

Tags: matlab

I need to plot two curves which share the same x axis but not the y. This can be achieved with plotyy.

However, the common x axis is to use the log scale, hence i would need to use semilogx.

I have tried the hold on, did not work.

My problem is that one can not combine plotyy with semilogx. Is there a solution to this vexing problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it:

```
t = 0:900; A = 1000; a = 0.005; b = 0.005;
z1 = A*exp(-a*t);
z2 = 2*A*exp(-a*t/2);
plotyy(t,z1,t,z2,'semilogx','semilogx');
```

Comment: +1, this is a good way to do it up front on creation of the plot. I added an answer with how to change the scale of a pre-existing axis as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [axes property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) `XScale`

```
set(gca,'XScale','log')
```

to change the axis scale to from `'linear'` (default) to `'log'`.  (The other axes work the same way).

With multiple sets of axes, you can find the handles of the children of the figure, and set this property on all of them.